# Is there a Game Boy Color emulator for Lion?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there a GBC emulator that will run on Lion? I've been in the mood for some nostalgic gaming recently, and I'd love to play some of the games from when I was younger.

Comment: I think this should be on Gaming.SE. I've flagged it for migration.

Comment: @daviesgeek This is about Mac software, it's OK to ask here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://vba.ngemu.com/
Visual Boy advanced should work on Mac. I haven't personally tried it out, but if it's at all as good as their program for PC you'll be set.
Best of luck

Comment: Already tried it, doesn't play Game Boy Color games.

Comment: Never mind, I modified some settings (removed the GameBoy Border, specifically) and it now works. I'll accept this answer anyways, though.

Answer (score 0):

VisualBoyAdvance is apparently a PowerPC Application that is able to run on Macs up to OS X Snow Leopard because those versions include a feature of being able to convert Power PC apps to Intel, which is what Macs are now with their Intel chipset.

Unfortunately they took out this feature from OS X Lion so it now ONLY ACCEPTS Intel applications. Therefore VisualBoyAdvance will not work on OS X Lion since it is Power PC. I have Snow Leopard though, so I am currently enjoying a nice session of Pokemon on VisualBoyAdvance on my Mac. Hope this helps

Comment: It probably doesn't help because the OP asked for a Lion solution...